# Animating multiple subplots using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to animate some sub-plots using matplotlib but I'm having problems getting it to work using FuncAnimation. Here is my animation function

```
def animate(i):
   global infection_data
   for p in people: 
       p.step()
       p.infect(people)

   position_data = np.array([p.pos for p in people])

   scatter.set_offsets(position_data)
   scatter.set_edgecolors(["k" if p.state == 0 else "r" for p in people])

   new_infection_data = np.array([i + 2, sum([1 if p.state == 1 else 0 for p in people])])
   infection_data = np.vstack((infection_data, new_infection_data))

   plot.set_data(infection_data[:,0], infection_data[:,1])

   return scatter, plot
```

The scatter and plot are on two different subplots. The scatter works as intended however there is no update to the line on the other subplot. How can I get this to animate?

Heres how I define scatter and plot

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
scatter = ax[0].scatter((), ())
plot, = ax[1].plot(infection_data[:,0], infection_data[:,1])
```

Comment: Could you show the lines where you define `scatter` and `plot`?

Comment: @taras Sure, I've edited the original.